# Which pronoun to to replace single antecedent?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, singular-they, antecedents

This is my all-time question. This time, I was writing specifications of my application and came up with this question. Which one of the following is more commonly used than the others? Note that I'm talking about a case without a relative pronoun.

- When a user logs in for the first time, **the user** has 6 invitations remaining
- When a user logs in for the first time, **the one** has 6 invitations remaining
- When a user logs in for the first time, **one** has 6 invitations remaining
- When a user logs in for the first time, **he/she** has 6 invitations remaining
- When a user logs in for the first time, **he** has 6 invitations remaining

Or, any other suggestions to get the sentence more natural?

Comment: I would use the last example, with 'he'. Of course, modern style-guides often prefer 'they' instead, which I find nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the most obvious version — and the most commonly heard:

> - When a user logs in for the first time, ***they*** have six invitations left.

Comment: Yes, *they* is most appropriate here. But I also have a problem with the tense used in the dependent clause.  It needs to be future tense as in: *When a user logs in for the first time, they will have six invitations available.*

Comment: Agree with you about they, but not about the tense. It's a difference of emphasis/perspective. e.g. "When an asteroid approaches a star, its path is deflected." vs. "When an asteroid approaches a star, its path will be deflected." #1 is describing the rules of the universe, which never change, and #2 is telling a story about the rules of the universe playing out in a specific, albeit hypothetical, instance. SUBTLE, yes, but I think either is appropriate for the OP's situation.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to describe a sequence of events, you could say "After a user has logged in, they may invite up to 6 other people," but personally, I think a better approach is to describe what users of the system can do, without requiring a sequence of events.  Most readers understand that logging in is a requirement for using a computer system.

Comment: such as:  "Each user may invite 6 people."

Comment: My goal is to know which pronoun is to replace single antecedent.   Not writing a decent sentence to describe how to use my application because my writings are notations in programing code to define behaviors of programming code. 

Since my question may lead misunderstanding, I will fix it.

Comment: I see, I thought "any other suggestions to get the sentence more natural" meant you were open to suggestion.  I would say "He/she can invite..." or "They can invite..." (but I won't type the rest of your sentence, since it has other issues).  hint: what is remaining?

Comment: Oh sorry. A user of my application initially has got limitation of number of people one can invite.

Comment: Oh, then you mean the user has 6 invitations remaining.  Ok, good luck!